# Pipe not returning any values in C

Tags: c, pipe

im new to pipes and have been reading over countless other questions and I cant seem to find the solution to my problem.

I initialize the pipes.

```
double f1sum[2];
int f1count[2];

if(pipe(f1sum) == -1 || pipe(f1count) == -1){
    printf("PIPE 1 FAILED");
}
```

In this method the first child writes a double and a int to a pipe.

```
close(f1sum[0]);
close(f1count[0]);
sleep(3);
//calculate file arg[1]
myFile = fopen (argv[1], "r");
double sum = 0;
if (&myFile == NULL)
{
    printf ("Error Reading File\n");
    exit (0);
}

double current;
double count;
while(fscanf(myFile, "%lf", &current) != EOF)
{
        
    sum = sum + current;
    count++;
}
printf("SUM HERE IS %fl \n", sum);
               
write(f1sum[1], &sum, sizeof(double));  
write(f1count[1], &count, sizeof(int));  
close(f1sum[1]);
close(f1count[1]);
```

At the end of my main method it is supposed to print the data written to these pipes but I am getting 0 for both.

```
//parent prints

sleep(5);
close(f1sum[1]);
close(f1count[1]);
int count1;
double sum1;

read(f1sum[0], &sum1, sizeof(double));
read(f1count[0], &count1, sizeof(int));

printf("FINAL SUM: %fl .. FINAL COUNT: %d", sum1, count1);
close(f1sum[0]);
close(f1count[0]);

return 0;
```

STDOUT: FINAL SUM: 0.000000001 .. FINAL COUNT: 0

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Actually checking the results of those `read` and `write` calls would be a worthy endeavor, since right now they're being completely ignored. As far as the code itself goes, a *proper* [mcve] that we can copy/paste/compile/run/replicate your issue with is needed.

Comment: Have you read the manual page for pipe i.e. [pipe](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html). So change `double f1sum[2];` to `int`

Comment: `&myFile == NULL` to `myFile == NULL` as well

Comment: @EdHeal Ok I changed the myFile thanks. I changed the double pipe to int still doesn't work.

Comment: @WhozCraig I could post if essential but it is a project for school and I'm not sure how my prof would feel if I posted the answer online

Comment: Change `while(fscanf(myFile, "%lf", &current) != EOF)` to `while(fscanf(myFile, " %lf", &current) != 1` - As the loop may be running forever otherwise

Comment: Please format the code so that it is readable

Comment: You need to seriously turn up your warning levels and treat them as errors. `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic` - there are numerous problems that will be identified if you do.

Comment: Consider indenting the code correctly. Will make it more readable

Comment: [These are what I'm referring to](https://pastebin.com/PiKfP5SN). Every one of these should be looked at at addressed in one form or another. And that's before even considering running the code and potentially debugging it.

Comment: @WhozCraig You are absolutely right. I changed everything from these warnings and the pipes work as expected. Thank you!